# How the diode in this circuit achieves AM modulation

Tags: rf, oscillator, communication, vhf

For the last week, I've been looking for a simple circuit to transmit VHF
analogue TV video signals, so that I can transmit my Raspberry Pi output to a TV set. Since I don't have enough experience in RF, I searched google for a design and got this:

[image]

To my understanding, it's a common-base oscillator running at almost 60 MHz,
question is: How can 1N4148 diode achieve modulation in this configuration,
and what this type of circuit is really called (RF engineering term)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diode in this circuit does not "achieve modulation". It's functioning as a "clamp" or "DC restoration" function so that the varying amplitude of the video does not affect the overall brighness in an objectionable way.

It serves to keep the tips of the sync pulses (the most negative voltage within the composite video signal, corresponding to maximum RF amplitude) at a fixed voltage value. The actual modulation occurs in the BE junction of the transistor.

Comment: Thanks , now I think I'm stupid for asking this question!! , BTW where can i find a good read about analogue communications in general?

Comment: Try second hand book stores and find some old electrics &  radio &  books intended for hobbyists and repairmen. The technology took leapfrogs in every decade of 1900's so you need many of them.